# Does Go slicing operator allocate new underlying array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I was reading this article which explains how slices in Go are implemented under the hood:
https://medium.com/swlh/golang-tips-why-pointers-to-slices-are-useful-and-how-ignoring-them-can-lead-to-tricky-bugs-cac90f72e77b

At the end of the article is this snippet of Go code:

```
func main() {
    slice:= make([]string, 1, 3)
  
    func(slice []string){
        slice=slice[1:3]
        slice[0]="b"
        slice[1]="b"
        fmt.Print(len(slice))
        fmt.Print(slice)
    }(slice)
    fmt.Print(len(slice)) 
    fmt.Print(slice)
}
```

My first guess was this would print:

```
2 [b b]3 [ b b]
```

In fact it prints:

```
2[b b]1[]
```

Which suggests that when anonymous function creates a new local slice by slicing the one passed to it as argument causes a new underlying array to be allocated for the slice. I've confirmed this with this modified version of code:

```
func main() {
    slice := make([]string, 1, 3)

    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
    fmt.Printf("adress of underlying array in main: %p\n", unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))

    func(slice []string) {
        hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
        fmt.Printf("adress of underlying array in func before slicing: %p\n", unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))
        slice = slice[1:3]
        slice[0] = "b"
        slice[1] = "b"
        hdr = (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
        fmt.Printf("adress of underlying array in func after slicing: %p\n", unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))
        fmt.Print(len(slice))
        fmt.Println(slice)
    }(slice)
    fmt.Print(len(slice))
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Which prints:

```
adress of underlying array in main: 0xc0000121b0
adress of underlying array in func before slicing: 0xc0000121b0
adress of underlying array in func after slicing: 0xc0000121c0
2[b b]
1[]
```

My question is: why is the slicing operation in anonymous function causing a new array to be allocated? My understanding was that if in main we are creating a slice with capacity 3, an underlying array with length 3 is created and when anonymous function is manipulating the slice, it is manipulating the same underlying array.

Comment: No, new underlying array is NOT allocated. https://go.dev/play/p/gdL9MZUt3ev. `1[]` is the output of printing `slice` in `main`. `2[b b]` is the output of printing `slice` in the anon func, which is a different variable, although both slices share the same underlying array.

Comment: The content of the underlying array is `["", "b", "b"]`, print in `main` only shows `1[]` because the slice in `main` is of length only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mkopriva mentioned, the reslicing does not reallocate anything. Reallocation happens only when appending new values would exceed the slice's **capacity** ([source](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)).

The output you got is because the elements you are "able to see" in a slice (including when you print it) depend on [its length](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types):

> The number of elements is called the length of the slice and is never negative. [...] The length of a slice s can be discovered by the built-in function `len`;

The original slice constructed with `slice := make([]string, 1, 3)`, has length=1, so when you print it, the output will be the **one** element at position `0` of the backing array, which is an empty string.

With this code:

```
slice = slice[1:3]
slice[0] = "b"
slice[1] = "b"
```

you are effectively mutating the elements at position `1` and `2` of the backing array, none of which is an element of the original slice.

If you reslice the original slice up to capacity — thus extending its *length*, it will print what you expect:

```
    slice = slice[:cap(slice)]
    fmt.Println(len(slice)) // 3
    fmt.Println(slice)      // [ b b]
                            //  ^ first is empty string
```